# How to validate only working Email in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to validate only working Email in JavaScript?
Actually, I want only working email excluding (@gmail.com, @outlook.com, @hotmail.com, @yahoo.com etc). I want only working emails like abc@stack.com etc.

Comment: What do you mean with "working email"? If you mean "a mailbox that exists and can receive email", you can't do that with just client-side code. That's why sites require you to verify your email address by clicking a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to get the domain part from the email, and check it against the list of personal email domains:

```js
const workingEmailValidator = email => 
    !['gmail', 'hotmail', 'yahoo', 'outlook'].includes(email.split('@')[1].split('.')[0])

console.log(workingEmailValidator('xyz@sss.com'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is also working!

```js
let text = "abc@hotmail.com";
let domain = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("@"));
if(domain == "@gmail.com" || domain == "@yahoo.com" || domain == "@hotmail.com" || domain == "@outlook.com"){
    console.error("Wrong format")
}else{
    console.log("working email")
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use my own function after checking if email is valid then you can check if it is work email or not :

```
const notAllowed = ["gmail.com", "email.com", "yahoo.com", "outlook.com"];
 function check(email) {
    const lastPortion = email.split("@")[1].toLowerCase();
     if (notAllowed.includes(lastPortion)) {
          console.log("Please enter work email");
          return false;
     }
     return true;
}
check("abc@paiman.com");
check("abc@gmail.com.com");
```